# How do I display a message in my WCF Application?

Tags: winforms, wcf

I am currently developing a WCF Publish Subscribe service on a windows form application. How do I code it such that whenever the publisher publish something, my WCF Service would display a message in the winforms app saying :

> Post has been sent to all subscribers at [Current Time]

Do I have to create another callback channel? Or just another service contract.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are publishing events by sending WCF calls from your windows forms application.

In this case you can do this with events.

When your WCF service sends the message, it also rasises an event. In the shell of your windows application you catch the event and display a message box.

Comment: I am publishing the event through a asp.net application. What do you mean by trying to catch the event? still pretty new in this area.